# Firebase: Host a folder to subdomain without creating new site

Tags: firebase-hosting, http-redirect

I have a website structured like this (where `build` is public directory of my firebase app) :

```
build/
├─ Creator/
│  ├─ index.html
├─ artist.html
├─ index.html
├─ song.html
├─ ...etc
```

The `build` directory is hosted at `myapp.com`
And I want to rewrite `myapp.com/Creator` to `creator.myapp.com`, and its descendants as well. How can I achieve such without creating another site on my Firebase hosting?

301 and 302 redirects do not work, and it's not intended for this I guess...
My `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "redirects": [{
      "type": 301,
      "source": "/Creator{,/**}",
      "destination": "https://creators.myapp.com"
    }],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "trailingSlash": false
  }
}
```